# ReactJs: Getting cannot read property 'setState' of undefined error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using axios with React to do a webservice get call and then set the state with the following code:

```
handleRefreshOrgs(e) {
    let curComponent = this;
    axios.get("/api/org").then((res) => {
        let result = JSON.parse(res.data[0]).result;
        curComponent.setState({
            scratchOrgs: result.scratchOrgs,
            nonScratchOrgs: result.nonScratchOrgs
        })
    });
}
```

I have tried multiple ways now to get this resolved inside the promise. However, none of the approaches I have tried worked. I have tried with declaring a new variable, using arrow function and using bind(). But none of them worked.

I am getting frustrated now. How should I resolve this issue?

Comment: why this: ` let curComponent = this;`;You are using arrow function, you can use `this.setState`. Is this not working for you.

Comment: Define handleRefreshOrgs with a fat arrow function or bind it to the class instance.

Comment: @Ved I have tried that before. It is not working for me. Otherwise I wouldn't have used the let thing

Comment: is 'result' returning the data correctly?

Comment: @Dream_Cap yes, it is.

Comment: di you bind `handleRefreshOrgs` like: `this.handleRefreshOrgs = this.handleRefreshOrgs.bind(this)` inside constructor?

Comment: you need to bind handleRefreshOrgs

Comment: @Ved May I know how to bind that?

Comment: @GiorgiMoniava May I know how to bind that?

Comment: added the way to bind . you can refer doc as well for better understanding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you have not bind your `handleRefreshOrgs` to `this`

```
class classname extends React.Component {
    constructor(){

    this.handleRefreshOrgs = this.handleRefreshOrgs.bind(this)
  }
    }
```

Refer this doc: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/react-binding-patterns-5-approaches-for-handling-this-92c651b5af56

Answer (score 1):

Your syntax looks correct. You need to bind it to the class. This is how you would bind it to the class. Here is the [documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/handling-events.html) and code:

```
class yourComponent extends React.Component {
constructor(){
//bind in the constructor
this.handleRefreshOrgs = this.handleRefreshOrgs.bind(this)
  }
}
```